# How to clear value textbox in SharePoint Online

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-online, remarkjs

I have an issue in the SharePoint Online environment.

I have control Name field 'Remark' with the scenario:
Before approver 1 to do approved on approvals process, approver 1 to do edit item in SharePoint, put Remark as a note for approver 2. after that approver 2 open item, edit item in SharePoint and to do the same thing with approver 1, put Remark as a note for approver 3.

is it can to Remark that has been inputted by approver 1 deleted automatically when the item is opened by approver 2?

[image]

Comment: please watch out your text, there are many errors.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you go to list settings and set the "**Append Changes to Existing Text**" of the "**Remark**" field to "**Yes**".

If you only want to use javascript, we can add the code below into script editor web part in edit form page to clear value of the "Remark" field.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("div[id^='Remark_'][id$='_$TextField_inplacerte']").text(""); 
});
</script>
```